# Keep the TRUE non-greedy match using Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds, non-greedy

From the following word "tacacatac", I want to match "cat".  It seems like the regex c.*?t should give me this, but I guess it starts with the first occurrence of "c" and then from there finds the next "t", and thus, matches "cacat".

Is there a way to (perhaps using negative lookahead) start looking from the c just before the final t?

-----edit-----
I need an option that will work if you replace the letters with strings

Thanks.

Comment: Why not `cat` directly?

Comment: because any letter can appear between the c and t..for example, it could have been cit or cot.  This is a simplification of what I need to do.  I actually need to capture words between two keywords which may appear a number of times in a document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
my $str = "the cat in the cat in the hat";
if ($str =~ /(cat(?:(?!cat).)*hat)/) {
    print $1, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Great.  It looks like that will do the trick.  I'm sure I can implement it, but not sure I completely understand why it works. Can you (or somebody) explain exactly how the syntax (?:(?!cat).)* works?

Answer (score 2):

You can use negated character class:

```
c[^ct]*t
```

This will match any character but `c` and `t` in between.

Comment: Thanks.  That will work for my example, but in reality, instaed of letters, I have words.  For example: "the cat in the cat in the hat" and I want to match the final "cat in the hat".  I guess this can't be done with a negated character class.

Comment: Why not just reverse your data and then match the first occurrence?

Comment: Hmm..I guess that's an option that would probably work. If there is not a straighforward way of doing it, I'll just use the reverse function twice!  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you reverse, you can match from beginning of the string `/^cat/`, or just use `/cat$/` or `/[Cc]at$/` to match cat at the end of the string.